# Windows like tabs in GNOME

Tags: gnome

Is there a way to use windows list like "tab list in a browser" ? Something like normal window list on a panel, but with a close button for each element of the list?
Is there such an extension : window list with close buttons for elements?
It probably can look like second picture, after applying changes to first picture.
Sorry if nobody needs this, I just wanted to know if there's  an option to do so.
[image]
[image]

Comment: In what program? In a file manager? Which one? In Gnome itself? What window list? What panel? Are you thinking of some applet shown on the gnome panel? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: I have edited the question. I'm looking for this kind of extension : window list with close buttons on elements. For GNOME itself. It may be an applet for mate panel or gnome panel, I don't know exactly.

Comment: Can't you just middle click on a window in the panel to close it?

Comment: It's less comfortable than close tab like in a browser.

Comment: I'm sorry but am not sure I understand correctly. My understanding is you are looking for a browser extension that will allow you to view multiple tabs at once and close whichever one you want. Is that right? If not, can you please explain?

Comment: @Rayleigh I think the OP is using Gnome and is talking about panel applets. Specifically, one that shows you a list of windows and allows you to close them from within that list. D. Smirnov, it would really help if you could include a screenshot of the panel applet you mean, because "window list" just has the buttons on the panel for each window and middle clicking those will close them. I doubt there will be any way of adding an X since that would just clutter the display for no real benefit given that middle clicking will do it already. I assume you mean some other type of list.

Comment: Rayleigh, I'm looking for GNOME extension that allows me to use window list with close button for each element. Just like tabs. There is an extension "Window list", but there is no way to add close button for each element.

Comment: Ok, I understand what you mean now, but the question of @terdon remains. Can you please provide us with a screenshot of what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: I did a screenshot, it probably looks like second picture after applying changes.

Comment: Yeah, OK. I really doubt anything like this exists given that you can close the window by middle-clicking anywhere. What benefit would there be in having an X?

Comment: @terdon, well, I know that looks strange and middle-click is an option. I don't know, for me it's more comfortable to use window list like tab list. Anyway, thanks all for your time and answers.